# How to determine the field value which can not convert to (decimal, float,int) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

I have a SQL Server database.

One field has values which are like

```
 ID      VALUE
  1      NEGATIF
  2      11.4
  3      0.2
  4      A RH(+)
  5      -----
  6      >>>>>
  7      5.6<
  8      -13.9
```

I want to CONVERT VALUE field to decimal, of course convert-able fields.

1. What kind of SQL statement can do this?
2. How can I understand which value is raising error while converting?

PS: I think this can solve  `WHERE VALUE LIKE '[a-z]'` but how can I add more filter like [-+ ()] ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Plain ISNUMERIC is rubbish

- Empty string, `+`, `-` and . are all valid
- So is `+.` etc
- `1e-3` is valid for float but not decimal (unless you CAST to float then to decimal)

For a particularly cryptic but failsafe solution, append `e0` or `.0e0` *then* use ISNUMERIC

```
SELECT
   ISNUMERIC(MyCOl + 'e0')   --decimal check,
   ISNUMERIC(MyCOl + '.0e0')  --integer check
```

So

```
SELECT
    ID, VALUE,
    CAST(
          CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(VALUE + 'e0') = 1 THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END
          AS decimal(38, 10)
        ) AS ConvertedVALUE
FROM
    Mytable
```

Comment: Just in case anybody else finds this neat trick - the integer check should actually add '.e0' not '.0e0'. Otherwise if the value you are testing is a single + or - character isnumeric() will still return true.

Comment: @Peter, you actually need something like this to handle the one character case: 

CAST(CASE WHEN LEN(Value) = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(VALUE + '.e0') = 1 THEN VALUE WHEN LEN(Value) > 1 AND ISNUMERIC(Value + '.0e0') = 1 THEN VALUE ELSE NULL END AS INT)

Comment: @EstebanBrenes - good catch. I obviously wasn't paying enough attention. I think in my case I only cared if it was a number I didn't care if it was an integer or decimal.

Comment: @Peter +1 for `.e0` to exclude '+', '-', and ''