# Convert varchar to float IF ISNUMERIC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that contains characters and numbers

```
12
13
14
19K/YR
22
```

So the column type is varchar. But then I'm also doing some computations with this column, so I'm trying to convert the data to float if it is numeric.

This gives me an error though:

```
SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC(QTY) 
         WHEN 1 THEN CAST(QTY AS float) 
         ELSE QTY 
       END AS test
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can't cast to float and keep the string in the same column. You can do like this to get null when isnumeric returns 0.

```
SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC(QTY) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(QTY AS float) ELSE null END
```

Comment: +1: Beat me to it - a column can not be more than one data type

Comment: Except, of course, for the fact that yet again ISNUMERIC falls down: `SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC('£2') WHEN 1 THEN CAST('£2' AS float) ELSE null END`. Has anyone ever discovered a circumstance where ISNUMERIC is usable without some fudging?

Comment: In SQL Server 2012+, you can use TRY_CONVERT():

Answer (score 13):

..extending Mikaels' answers

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(QTY + 'e0') = 1 THEN CAST(QTY AS float) ELSE null END AS MyFloat
  CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(QTY + 'e0') = 0 THEN QTY ELSE null END AS MyVarchar
FROM
  ...
```

- Two data types requires two columns
- Adding `e0` fixes some ISNUMERIC [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522056/how-to-determine-the-field-value-which-can-not-convert-to-decimal-float-int-in/4522185#4522185) (such as `+` `-` `.` and empty string being accepted)

Comment: Unlike the usual questions involving `int`s, this one involves conversion to `float` - so what if the QTY value is already `'1.5e10'` (which can be converted to float)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: it fails in this case. Personally I use decimals mostly so never had the need to work it out fully

Answer (score 2):

I found this very annoying bug while converting EmployeeID values with ISNUMERIC:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [EmployeeID],
ISNUMERIC(ISNULL([EmployeeID], '')) AS [IsNumericResult],

CASE WHEN COALESCE(NULLIF(tmpImport.[EmployeeID], ''), 'Z')
    LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 'NonNumeric' ELSE 'Numeric'
END AS [IsDigitsResult]
FROM [MyTable]
```

This returns:

```
EmployeeID IsNumericResult MyCustomResult
---------- --------------- --------------
           0               NonNumeric
00000000c  0               NonNumeric
00D026858  1               NonNumeric

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

**-- TRY THIS --**

```
select name= case when isnumeric(empname)= 1 then 'numeric' else 'notmumeric' end from [Employees]
```

But conversion is quit impossible

```
select empname=
case
when isnumeric(empname)= 1 then empname
else 'notmumeric'
end
from [Employees]
```