# Changing AND condition of a INNER JOIN based on a flag?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case, inner-join

I need to be able to change an AND condition of an inner join based on a flag.  I tried the following based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition), and while it compiles, when you run it never completes.  Any thoughts?

```
SELECT Stuff, ...
FROM Table t1
    INNER JOIN ...
    INNER JOIN ...
    ...
    INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE t2 ON 
        CASE
            WHEN @ParticipantsFlag = 'S' AND t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.STUDENT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            WHEN @ParticipantsFlag = 'A' AND t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.ADULT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END = 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*never*"? How many hours have you waited?

Comment: I'd advice you to make either multiple individual queries and call the correct one - or use dynamic SQL. Will give you better performance and maintainability.

Comment: It takes a long time to run possibly because your join condition isn't a comparison of fields it's a comparison of your case statement equal to 1.

Comment: @PM77-1 Long enough to realize I'd made a terrible mistake :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Stuff, ...
FROM Table t1
    INNER JOIN ...
    INNER JOIN ...
    ...
    INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE t2 
       ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
      AND ( ( @ParticipantsFlag = 'S' 
              AND t2.STUDENT_ID IS NOT NULL )
            or
            ( @ParticipantsFlag = 'A' 
              AND t2.ADULT_ID IS NOT NULL )
          )
```

+1 to linoff but I this may be more efficient two join approach

```
 LEFT JOIN OTHER_TABLE t2s 
        ON t1.ID = t2s.ID 
       AND @ParticipantsFlag = 'S' 
 LEFT JOIN OTHER_TABLE t2a 
        ON t1.ID = t2a.ID 
       AND @ParticipantsFlag = 'A' 
WHERE t2s.STUDENT_ID IS NOT NULL 
   or t2a.ADULT_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That what I was going to propose.

Comment: Ending up going with this.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

`or` conditions in joins can be quite expensive.  I would recommend that you join the table twice:

```
LEFT JOIN
OTHER_TABLE t2s
ON @ParticipantsFlag = 'S' and
   t1.ID = t2.ID AND
   t2.STUDENT_ID IS NOT NULL LEFT JOIN
OTHER_TABLE t2a
ON  @ParticipantsFlag = 'A' AND
    t1.ID = t2.ID AND
    t2.ADULT_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Note the use of `left join` instead of `inner join`.

Then adjust the `select` and `where` clauses to get what you need from the two tables.  To handle the implicit filtering of one-or-the-other:

```
where (t2s.id is not null or t2a.id is not null)
```

To combine the values in the select, use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(t2s.name, t2a.name) as name
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this, you've created a nonsargable predicate for this join.

By this, I mean that your criteria cannot be evaluated using index lookups -- the system will need to evaluate the `CASE` statement for every potential row in the `JOIN`, and this is almost certainly very slow.

A possible refactoring that might help would be this, since the criteria `t1.ID = t2.ID` is the same for both branches of your `CASE`:

```
SELECT Stuff, ...
FROM Table t1
    INNER JOIN ...
    INNER JOIN ...
    ...
    INNER JOIN OTHER_TABLE t2 ON 
        t1.ID = t2.ID AND
        CASE
            WHEN @ParticipantsFlag = 'S' AND t2.STUDENT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            WHEN @ParticipantsFlag = 'A' AND t2.ADULT_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END = 1
```

Note that we've pulled out the primary ID relation into a "standard" form.  This will allow an index seek to be used for this comparison, which should be much faster for you.

Comment: You can go even further and add `AND (firstWhenCondition OR secondWhenCondition)` to `ON` clause eliminating `CASE` statements . This way if the 1st is true then the 2nd wouldn't be evaluated.  Plus it *could* make it easier for query optimizer to digest.

Comment: @PM77-1 that is what I did

Comment: @Blam - Yes, I noticed.

Comment: If `firstWhenCondition` is OR-ed with `secondWhenCondition`, both of them will have to be evaluated to determine whether the parenthetical expression as a whole is true or not.  Plus, a clause that doesn't include any table references (such as `@ParticipantsFlag = 'S'`) ends up evaluated for every row anyway.  Pretty sure it ends up being a wash.