# T-SQL Case Condition in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i trying to do this query where i have a **where clause**. The problem is that i need to use inside the where condition the operator IN but i can´t figured out 
what i missing.

someone can give a hand pls?

here is my query

```
DECLARE @OP INT = 1
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE
Table.[status] IN (CASE WHEN @OP = 1 THEN (5,6) ELSE (12) END)
```

Comment: You can use a CASE like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need for a case statement.

```
DECLARE @OP INT = 1;
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (@OP = 1 AND Table.[status] IN (5,6))
OR (@OP !=1 AND Table.[status] IN (12))
```

Comment: it's `case` expression, not statement

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
DECLARE @OP INT = 1
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE
((@OP = 1 AND TABLE.[status] IN (5,6)) OR (@OP <> 1 AND  TABLE.[status] = 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
DECLARE @OP INT = 1
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE
1 = (CASE WHEN @OP = 1 CASE WHEN Table.[status] IN (5,6) THEN 1 END
          ELSE CASE WHEN Table.[status] = 12 THEN 1 END  
     END)
```

Having nested case statements *may* help the query plan take advantage of case statement short circuiting. You could also do it like this without the nested cases:

```
DECLARE @OP INT = 1
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE
1 = (CASE WHEN @OP = 1 AND Table.[status] IN (5,6) THEN 1 
          WHEN @OP <> 1 AND Table.[status] = 12 THEN 1   
     END)
```

Comment: It is a little clearer if you include an `ELSE` clause in the `CASE` expressions to explicitly provide a default value, e.g. zero. Otherwise a `NULL` will be returned and some people don't cope, or code, well with nulls.

Comment: yes, possibly. I generally prefer to leave out the "ELSE 0" parts in queries like this because it makes the code more compact (and I know NULL is never "equal" to anything). Others may find it helps to make things clearer.