# how to cascade CASE sql inside the condition WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

- I am searching for a word match for the variable- @TextSearchWord
- I have a @SearchCriteria variable which may have 5 values!
- According to that value, i choose from **which field** i have to search my word!

-so i need to cascade the "CASE" statement inside the "WHERE" statement only and like other samples here inside the select statement !

```
SELECT COUNT(WordID) AS WordQty
FROM itinfo_QuranArabicWordsAll
WHERE (SiteID = @SiteID) 
AND (QuranID = @QuranID) 
AND (SuraID BETWEEN @StrtSuraID AND @EndSuraID) 
AND (VerseOrder BETWEEN @StrtVerseSortOrder AND @EndVerseSortOrder)
AND ( 
        -- here is my problem : 
        CASE 
          WHEN (@SearchCriteria = 'DictNM') THEN  (WordDictNM = @TextSearchWord )
          ELSE CASE 
                 WHEN (@SearchCriteria = 'DictNMAlif') THEN (WordDictNMAlif = @TextSearchWord)  
                 ...
               END        
        END
    )
```

Comment: I'm not 100% on tsql, however, the CASE structure is typically:  `CASE WHEN <condition1> THEN <result1> WHEN <condition2> THEN <condition2> ... <repeat as needed> END`.  That said, if you have multiple values for a single variable, often CASE also allows: `CASE <variable> WHEN <value1> THEN <result1> WHEN <value2> THEN <result2> .... END` ... might be either of those work for you ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) may help a bit. `CASE` expressions can be nested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a `CASE` statement for this.

```
SELECT     COUNT(WordID) AS WordQty
FROM         itinfo_QuranArabicWordsAll
WHERE (SiteID = @SiteID) 
    AND (QuranID = @QuranID) 
    AND (SuraID BETWEEN @StrtSuraID AND @EndSuraID) 
    AND (VerseOrder BETWEEN @StrtVerseSortOrder AND @EndVerseSortOrder)
    AND (
        (@SearchCriteria = 'DictNM' AND WordDictNM = @TextSearchWord )
        OR (@SearchCriteria = 'DictNMAlif' AND WordDictNMAlif = @TextSearchWord)
        ...
)
```

Comment: ok,
thank you
i will take this method, i think case will not work in my issue!!

Answer (score 3):

[SQL WHERE clauses: Avoid CASE, use Boolean logic](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/14/513.aspx).

```
....
AND(
    ( @SearchCriteria = 'DictNM'     AND WordDictNM     = @TextSearchWord )   
 OR ( @SearchCriteria = 'DictNMAlif' AND WordDictNMAlif = @TextSearchWord ) 
)
```