# T-SQL. CASE expression in WHERE clause using IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

If user put 800 as `@WorkShop` It should return all records having 800 workshop Id and 900 workshop id.

If user pass any other Id as `@WorkShop` It should return only records for choosen `@WorkShop` Id.

I have tried in following:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE Workshop IN ( 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN @WorkShop = N'800' THEN N'900' AND N'800' 
                        ELSE @WorkShop 
                    END 
                    )
```

This returns an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.
```

So in conclusion if user pass 800 as `@WorkShop` parameter It should return something like:

```
Workshop IN ('800', '900')
```

Comment: If you do need to use a `CASE` expression in a `WHERE` (or `JOIN`/`ON`) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) may be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE ( @WorkShop = '800' AND  Workshop IN('800', '900') )
OR @WorkShop =  Workshop
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate method

```
SELECT *
FROM   Test
WHERE  Workshop IN ( @WorkShop, CASE
                                  WHEN @WorkShop = N'800' THEN N'900'
                                END )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE (@WorkShop = '800' AND  (Workshop = '800' or  Workshop = '900'))
OR @WorkShop =  Workshop
```