# case statement in where clause SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried searching around but couldn't find anything that would help me out.

I'm trying to do this in SQL:

```
DECLARE @onlyMM INT

SET @onlyMM = 1

SELECT *
FROM cdn.magnag
WHERE CASE @onlyMM
        WHEN 1
            THEN man_zrdtyp NOT IN (
                    1616
                    ,2001
                    )
        ELSE - 1
        END
```

I have a problem with:

```
where case @onlyMM when 1 then man_zrdtyp not in (1616,2001) else -1 end
```

how to properly make a `case` for the operator `not in`?

Comment: It should be case when @onlyMM = 1 then man_zrdtyp not in (1616,2001) else -1 end

Comment: I think both are fine. @Dr.Stitch

Comment: First of all what is else -1? You understand that your where CLAUSE is "where -1" now?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) demonstrates using `case` in a `join`, similar to a `where`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do this?

```
where (case when @onlyMM = 1 then man_zrdtyp else -1 end) not in (1616,2001)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to formulate the `WHERE` clause in a different way. You could use `OR` instead of case statement. Like this:

```
WHERE
    (@onlyMM=1 AND man_zrdtyp not in (1616,2001))
    OR @onlyMM<>1
```

Comment: `NOT @onlyMM=1` difficult to read. `@onlyMM<>1` I think is better.