# Conditional joining in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a DB table to store rudimentary history. I'm trying to keep it super generic.

The table looks like:

```
HistoryID   Action      Table       PrimaryKey  Field           OldValue    NewValue            User                DateTime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
240233      Added       QueueItem   17177       QueueItemID     17177                           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:38:58.060
240237      Modified    QueueItem   17177       StatusTypeID    1           2                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:38:59.163
240240      Modified    QueueItem   17177       StatusTypeID    2           3                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:00.850
240241      Modified    QueueItem   17177       PackageID       0                               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:00.850
240249      Modified    QueueItem   17177       StatusTypeID    3           4                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:09.207
240256      Modified    QueueItem   17177       StatusTypeID    4           5                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:10.163
240257      Modified    QueueItem   17177       OutputDateTime              9/16/2016 8:39:10   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:10.163
```

What I am wondering is possible, is to conditionally join depending on the value of `Field`. I imagine I would have to use t-SQL though I'm a little stuck.

I could do individual selects with a where on the field and then union all my results but wasn't sure if there was a better way?

pseudo-code would be something like:

```
select h.*, s.[name] from history h 
    some kind of condition that when satified joins the statusType table and if not, then perhaps sets s.[name] to null
```

I tried something like this, and it works for 'StatusFrom' but not with 'StatusTo' - fails because it cannot convert the date in the last row to an int.

```
select h.*, 
       so.[Name] as StatusFrom, 
       sn.[Name] as StatusTo 
from history h
left outer join StatusType so 
             on so.StatusTypeID = Convert(int, h.OldValue) 
            AND 1 = case WHEN h.field = 'StatusTypeID' 
                         THEN 1
                         else 0
                    end
left outer join StatusType sn
             on sn.StatusTypeID = Convert(int, h.NewValue) 
            AND 1 = case WHEN h.field = 'StatusTypeID' 
                         THEN 1
                         else 0 
                    end
where primarykey = 17177
```

I would provide more code example though I am just super stuck.

I guess i only really want the actual join if a condition is met. Is this something that's possible?

**Update**

Expected result would be:

```
HistoryID   Action      Table       PrimaryKey  Field           OldValue    NewValue            User                DateTime                StatusFrom      StatusTo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
240233      Added       QueueItem   17177       QueueItemID     17177                           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:38:58.060     NULL            NULL
240237      Modified    QueueItem   17177       StatusTypeID    1           2                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:38:59.163     New             Building
240240      Modified    QueueItem   17177       StatusTypeID    2           3                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:00.850     Building        Ready
240241      Modified    QueueItem   17177       PackageID       0                               XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:00.850     NULL            NULL
240249      Modified    QueueItem   17177       StatusTypeID    3           4                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:09.207     Ready           Processing
240256      Modified    QueueItem   17177       StatusTypeID    4           5                   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:10.163     Processing      Done
240257      Modified    QueueItem   17177       OutputDateTime              9/16/2016 8:39:10   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 2016-09-16 08:39:10.163     NULL            NULL
```

Per SWE answer, i tried this too:

```
select h.*, so.[Name] as StatusFrom, sn.[Name] as StatusTo from history h
    left outer JOIN StatusType so on so.StatusTypeID = Convert(int, h.NewValue)  and h.field = 'statustypeid'
    left outer JOIN StatusType sn on sn.StatusTypeID = Convert(int, h.NewValue)  and h.field = 'statustypeid'
 where primarykey = 17177
```

I get the same issue - falls over when it hits the date in the newValue field

Comment: since you are doing left joins you condition will not leave out any records but only make them null. Is that what you wanted / expected ?

Comment: yes. I need to bring back all the history but where there is a field of statusTypeID then i would like to join to the status table to get the text name.

Comment: sorry but I dont see the expected result.

Comment: Sorry - I will add one

Comment: A suggestion would be to add an additional column to the history table with the relevant information from the foreign table, as that value could be changed/deleted too -- history table should be immune to external changes.

Comment: @RubensFarias - You're absolutely correct. It should be a complete snapshot. Perhaps I will re-work it. I would like to know if my Q is possible though.

Answer (score 0):

Joining to dynamic table is not supported.

You have do go through a tsql-stored-procedure with some cursour-logic and build your result set by hand.

OR, if you have only a handfull of possible tables, join everyone and set conditions that only evaluate to true, if you would like to "join" each table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id AND a.table = 'b' and a.field = 'id'
LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.something AND a.table = 'b' and a.field = 'something'
LEFT JOIN c...
```

Maybe some kind of subselect in the SELECT-statement is better and more easy to read, if you just want one value of some child-table.

Comment: Ref your 'Or' statement - that's what I tried to do in my example. I added an update showing my new code and i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was so very close with my initial script.

Help from this answer [Can I use CASE statement in a JOIN condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition) allowed me to come up with this, which gives me my expected results:

```
select h.*, so.[Name] as StatusFrom, sn.[Name] as statusto from history h
    left outer join StatusType so 
        on 
        case
        when h.field='StatusTypeID' and so.StatusTypeID = Convert(int, h.OldValue)  then 1  
        else 0
        end = 1
    left outer join StatusType sn
        on case
        when h.field='StatusTypeID' and sn.StatusTypeID = Convert(int, h.NewValue)  then 1  
        else 0
        end = 1
 where primarykey = 17177
```