# SQL CASE statement with LIKE (MSG 156)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This part of code is in a WHERE clause:

```
AND
  C = CASE
    WHEN @Variable = 'NA' THEN C
    ELSE LIKE '%' + @Variable + '%'
  END
```

Here's what I want: If @Variable is 'NA'(as in not applicable), then give me all results. If not, I want only C like @Variable.

The error is with the like. If I remove the = from C = CASE, there's no more error with LIKE, but the error is with CASE instead. How should I proceed?

Comment: I agree that the answers below are probably better. To address your syntax problem though: `WHEN C LIKE '%' + @Variable + '%' THEN C` instead of the `ELSE`.

Comment: Remember that `case` is an expression. It returns a value not a boolean condition.

Comment: Also remember to be careful with `or`. Usually you need to wrap `or`s with parentheses to get the correct precedence.

Comment: @shawnt00 Then how can I select everything if Variable = 'NA'?

Comment: Leave that part in. I was just talking about what you had as `else.

Comment: You've written something akin to either `C = C` or `C = LIKE '%' + @Variable + '%'`, which doesn't make sense. A `case` expression can be used, as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) example, but `where @Variable = 'NA' or C like '%' + @Variable + '%'` seems simpler and clearer.

Comment: Forgot to mention: `where C = C` will not return all rows if `C` can be `NULL`.

Comment: @HABO I was aware of that, but I didn't feel like explaining null logic at the time. You'll notice that I avoided that problem in my answer below though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax will never work, and why go for something so complicated?

```
WHERE (@var = 'ok') OR (c like '%' + @var + '%')
```

Comment: 'OK' isn't part of the table. I edited my question and replaced OK with N/A

Comment: irrelevant. it's just a string. and changing your question AFTER the fact basically invalidates all of these answers.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a simple `WHERE`, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE (@Variable = 'OK') OR (C LIKE '%' + @Variable + '%')
```

Comment: 'OK' isn't part of the table. I'll change my question. N/A would be more appropriate.

Comment: So then replace `OK` with `NA`...?

Comment: what does it matter if it is/isn't part of the table? a `where` doesn't have to involve a table/field AT ALL. a where clause boils down to a boolean true/false, and ANY expression which produces true/false is valid for a `where`. true = include the record, false = exclude. that means `where 1` or `where 1=0` or `where 'a'='a'` are all valid.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately what you want is `OR`. I recommend using that approach, as given by the other answers, however it is indeed possible to fix your syntax problem using `CASE`.

```
AND
  'Keep' = CASE
    WHEN @Variable = 'NA' THEN 'Keep'
    WHEN C LIKE '%' + @Variable + '%' THEN 'Keep'
    ELSE 'Discard'
  END
```

I tried to also highlight that the values being compared don't really matter nor is the `ELSE` strictly necessary.