# IF/Else/CASE Statement in WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I am selecting records from has a column called [tagged], and it's defaulted to Zero.
My problem is when the `@tagged` variable is `NULL`, then I want to select both 0,1 values.  This makes me think I should be doing an `IF/ELSE`, but my attempts are failing.

--- simple example:

```
declare @tagged int = NULL

SELECT * 
FROM [TableName] 
WHERE datecreated > '2016-01-01' 
AND tagged = @tagged
```

---

Many DBAs are recommending the CASE clause. 
But I need help knowing where to add it.

Do I add it inside the Query?

My feeble attempt was this:

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TableName] 
WHERE datecreated > '2016-01-01' 
AND (
    CASE @tagged 
    WHEN 0 THEN (tagged = 0) 
    WHEN 1 THEN (tagged = 1)
    ELSE (tagged IN(0,1)
    END
)
```

Comment: A `CASE` can be used in a `JOIN` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10260297/92546). A `WHERE` clause can use the same pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OR` condition rather than chunky `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM   [TableName]
WHERE  datecreated > '2016-01-01'
       AND ( tagged = @tagged
              OR @tagged IS NULL )
```

In case you are looking to solve it using `CASE` then (considering there are no `NULL` values in `tagged` column)

```
WHERE  datecreated > '2016-01-01'
       AND tagged = CASE
                      WHEN @tagged IS NOT NULL THEN @tagged
                      ELSE tagged
                    END
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  In my case there are no NULL values, so it made sense how you formatted the CASE structure.

Comment: @coffeemonitor - Gald it helped you..I prefer `OR` condition.. Which is simple & more readable