# select multiple values in case statement when using "in"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to figure out if is it possible to do a statement like this :

```
select * from telephone
where TEL_number like @tel_number
and TEL_cat in (case 
                   when @tel_number_cat = 0 
                     then 5                           
                   else 1 or 3
                 end)
```

Is there a way to do a select where TEL_number like `@tel_number` and if `@tel_number_cat = 0` then `TEL_cat = 5` `else TEL_cat = 1 or 3`

Is it possible to use `CASE` Statement in `WHERE IN ()` clause but in the `ELSE` I need to get 2 category of numbers (1,3)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10260297/92546) answer show how to use `case` and `in`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
select * from telephone
where TEL_number like @tel_number
and 
(

    (TEL_cat = 5 and @tel_number_cat = 0)
    OR
    (TEL_cat IN (1,3) and @tel_number_cat <> 0)

)
```