# where case condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
(case when @InAct = 1 then (pck.packageID = (select pa.packageID  from PakacgeTb pa where (pck.packageID = pa.packageID)

 and 

((cast(pck.expirydate as date) > cast(getdate() as date)) and cast(pck.BalanceVisit as decimal) > cast(0.00 as decimal)))))
```

*i am trying to use the where case condition i don't know how to use it. This whole code is used after a where condition.*

Comment: You didn't END your CASE statement. You also really didn't begin it properly.

Comment: please provide whole statement and the error encountered

Comment: well even if i do their would be error shown

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. This case expression can't work. `then x=y` is not how `case` works. `CASE` returns an atomic value.

Comment: You need to give us more information on what you are trying to do. Your entire statement and your desired result would help. From your code, all we can tell is that you made obvious errors, but we can't help you solve the problem if we don't know what the actual problem is.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) answer may be helpful, whatever the question is.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `CASE` expression with a compound condition in `WHERE` clause like

```
where (@InAct = 1 or @InAct is null)
and pck.packageID in (select pa.packageID  
                       from PakacgeTb pa)
and 
((cast(pck.expirydate as date) > cast(getdate() as date)) 
and cast(pck.BalanceVisit as decimal) > cast(0.00 as decimal))))
```

Comment: i like the method but how do i check on condition say @InAct = 1 if it is null then .. Thats why i was using case condition .. ?

Comment: @rinki, use `coalesce()` function ... see edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: lets say i want to avoid this code in the condition using @InAct as null and using some other OR,AND condition

Comment: Example IF condition InAct = 1 else InAct is null because i want to show my table with all values and i want this method to filter out my results using the InAct = 1 else InAct is null.

Comment: @rinki, you should clarify this at first and not in comment but edit your post and include them. anyways you can use a `or` condition. see edit again

Answer (score 0):

A simple structure of Case

```
select 
CASE when ISNULL(pa.[packageID],1) = 1 then 'do something' 
else 'do something' 
end   
from PakacgeTb pa
```

---

You have to use **then** for the **when** condition. see below.

```
and (CASE when coalesce(@InAct,1) = 1 and pck.packageID in (select 
pa.packageID from PakacgeTb pa) and ((cast(pck.expirydate as date) > 
cast(getdate() as date)) and cast(pck.BalanceVisit as decimal) > cast(0.00 
as decimal))

then 'do something'

else 'this will only execute if when condition does not satisfy'

end
```

Comment: and (CASE when coalesce(@InAct,1) = 1 and pck.packageID in (select pa.packageID from PakacgeTb pa) and ((cast(pck.expirydate as date) > cast(getdate() as date)) and cast(pck.BalanceVisit as decimal) > cast(0.00 as decimal)) else @InAct is null end) ... like this type i want

Comment: here you have not used **then** .

Comment: `and (CASE when coalesce(@InAct,1) = 1 and pck.packageID in (select pa.packageID from PakacgeTb pa) and ((cast(pck.expirydate as date) > cast(getdate() as date)) and cast(pck.BalanceVisit as decimal) > cast(0.00 as decimal))

then 'do something'

else 'this will execute when first when the condition does not satisfy'

end`

Comment: @Azhar, maybe it's clearer if you use `return something` rather than `do something` in your examples. Case doesn't do anything, it returns a value. `do something` sounds too much like an `if` statement in procedural languages.

Comment: Correct @HoneyBadger here rinki can return any column value as per his requirements.