# How to choose 1 record from 2 tables based on record existence?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, illustrated by queries:

**CT_Validation**

```
select ValidationID, Message from CT_Validation

ValidationID    Message
======================================================
IP_Validator    Not a valid IP address
NumbersOnly     Invalid number.
SSN             Not a valid social security number.
10Digits        A 10-digit number is required.
```

**CT_Validation_Lang**

```
select ValidationID, LangID, Message from CT_Validation_Lang
    
ValidationID  LangID  Message
======================================================
SSN           es      Peligro es mi segundo nombre!
```

How would I build a join so that if `LangID = 'es'` I would get back:

```
ValidationID    Message
======================================================
IP_Validator    Not a valid IP address
NumbersOnly     Invalid number.
SSN             Peligro es mi segundo nombre!
10Digits        A 10-digit number is required.
```

...but if `LangID` is blank, null, or anything other than 'es', the results would revert to all English:

```
ValidationID    Message
======================================================
IP_Validator    Not a valid IP address
NumbersOnly     Invalid number.
SSN             Not a valid social security number.
10Digits        A 10-digit number is required.
```

Important: The key field is `ValidationID` and the important key value in this example is `SSN` because that exists in both tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use CASE statement in a JOIN condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `left join` and `coalesce`

```
select cv.ValidationID, coalesce(cvl.Message, cv.Message) 
from CT_Validation cv
left join CT_Validation_Lang cvl on cv.ValidationID = cvl.ValidationID
     and cvl.LangID = 'es'
```

This will select the `Message` from the `CT_Validation_Lang` if it exists for `LangID` `es`. Otherwise it will fall back to the `Message` from `CT_Validation`

Comment: Works great! Thank you FuzzyTree.

Answer (score 1):

One way with `CASE`

```
SELECT
  ctv.ValidationID,
  CASE WHEN ctvl.LangID = 'es' THEN ctvl.message ELSE ctv.message END AS Message
FROM CT_Validation ctv
LEFT JOIN CT_Validation_Lang ctvl ON ctv.ValidationId = ctvl.ValidationId
  AND ctvl.LangID = 'es'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select v.ValidationID, coalesce(vl.message, v.message) as message
from CT_Validation v left join
     CT_Validation_Lang vl
     ON vl.ValidationID = v.ValidationID and vl.LangID = 'es';
```

This will choose the message from `CT_Validation_Lang` when the Spanish translation is available.  Otherwise, it chooses the original message.

Answer (score 0):

Something like: -

```
select 
  ctv.ValidationID, 
  coalesce(
          (select 
             ctvl.Message 
           from 
             CT_Validation_Lang ctvl 
           where 
             ctvl.ValidationID = ctv.ValidationID and 
             LangID = 'es'
           ), 
           ctv.Message, ' ') as Message 
  from 
    CT_Validation ctv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ISNULL()` function together with a `left join`.

```
select a.ValidationID, ISNULL(b.message, a.message) 
from CT_Validation a
left join CT_Validation_Lang b on a.ValidationID = b.ValidationID and b.LangID = 'es'
```