# CASE Statement in WHERE statement (equal to and not equal to)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query where I'm trying to return different values from a table based off the values of a bit variable.

Is there a way I can substitute the where condition to get that to work?

```
DECLARE @isAggregate bit = 0

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Fields
WHERE
    FieldType  
    CASE 
        WHEN @isAggregate = 1 THEN = 'Aggregate'
        WHEN @isAggregate = 0 THEN <> 'Aggregate'
    END
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) demonstrates how to use a `case` _expression_ in a `join` condition. It works the same way in a `where` clause. Depending on the logic involved there may be much more efficient ways to write a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use boolean logic, case `expression` will not work in this way :

```
where (@isAggregate = 1 and FieldType = 'Aggregate') or
      (@isAggregate = 0 and FieldType <> 'Aggregate')
```