# How can you use if statement in a left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

The column is varchar. the column either has a plus or minus sign at the end. For example 00096.45- or 00089.44+ . I need to check to see if the column has a '+' or a '-' sign. if it has a plus sign i multiply by 1 if it has a minus sign i have to multiply by -1 then get the sum. This statement needs to be done in a left join, I am not able to post the table. Is this possible?

Comment: If you cannot post the table, can you at least post your attempts at writing the query to show what work you've already done and give us a place to start?

Comment: check out using a case statement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you really just want the absolute value...

```
select 
    t1.column
   ,sum(t2.column) theSum
from 
    table1 t1
    left join
       table2 t2 on t1.column = left(t2.column,len(t2.column) - 1)
group by
    t1.column
```

Note here I'm *dropping* your sign which would return the absolute value which usually would be done with the [abs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function if this wasn't a `varchar`