# T-SQL CASE statement returning a different filter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column named `TimeSlots` that holds a twelve hour range of dates, `7:00:00` thru `19:00:00`.

I have a stored procedure that accepts a `varchar` parameter that could be 'AM' or 'PM'. I am using a CASE expression inside the WHERE to get either:

- `Time-Slots < 12:00:00` for AM times
- `TimeSlots >= '12:00:00'` for PM times.

It ain't working. Following is the example that i tried:

```
AND [TimeSlot] = CASE WHEN @ApptTime = 'AM' THEN [TimeSlot] < '12:00:00'
                                 WHEN @ApptTime = 'PM' THEN [TimeSlot] >= '12:00:00'
```

How can this be done?

Comment: How *It ain't working*? Any error messages?

Comment: You can use a `case` _expression_ like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how `CASE` expressions (not statements) work. They can only evaluate to a single value.

You can just use Boolean expressions to do what you want.

```
...
AND (@ApptTime = 'AM'
     AND [TimeSlot] < '12:00:00'
      OR @ApptTime = 'PM'
         AND [TimeSlot] >= '12:00:00')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want use multiple SELECT statements in SP to get the result based on parameter value (`AM` or `PM`). Following is the example:

```
IF @AppTime = 'AM'
    BEGIN
     SELECT ....
     FROM ....
     WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,[TimeSlot]) < 12
   END

IF @AppTime = 'PM'
    BEGIN
     SELECT ....
     FROM ....
     WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,[TimeSlot]) >= 12
   END
```

Comment: That works.  It's what I was going to do originally, but I didn't want to end up with all the additional lines of code.