# TSQL How do I filter inside of a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to filter by a date/get all options without a date ONLY WHEN @getdisabledoptions = 0, otherwise if @getdisabledoptions = 1 I want to get all of the options.

```
WHERE AffiliationID = @AffiliationID
AND  
case
```

this is the case that I want to filter by disabled date or get null values if @getdisabledoptions = null

```
when @GetDisabledOptions = 0 then DisabledDate > GETDATE() or DisabledDate = IS NULL
```

otherwise here I want to just pull everything where AffiliationId = @affiliationId and not filter by date

```
else end
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried to look up other answers but I'm just not wording something right.

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this without a case statement? I'd like to know both ways if possible.

Comment: `else 1 end` also there shouldn't be an `=` in `DisabledDate = IS NULL`

Comment: @Nick still getting "invalid syntax near >"

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. `CASE` returns a single atomic value: [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It's not a `Switch` statement (`Case` statements do not exist in T-SQL). Don't use a `CASE` **expression** in your `WHERE` though, use proper boolean logic with `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: The tag you have used (`case`) also tells you this: *"In SQL, the CASE expression evaluates a list of conditions, returning the result for the first condition which evaluates to true. For programming languages' CASE questions, use the [switch-statement] tag instead."*

Comment: Apart from there is a prior `AND`, @Nick . So, regardless of the value of `@AffiliationID` you would end up with any row that has a value of `NULL` for `DisabledDate`, for example. I actually thought you had `@GetDisabledOptions = 0` at first, but actually the whole thing should be wrapped in parenthesis if you're using `1`.

Comment: @Larnu you're right, the entire expression should be enclosed in parentheses i.e. `(@GetDisabledOptions = 1 or DisabledDate > GETDATE() or DisabledDate IS NULL)`

Comment: @CodyStorch [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) answer demonstrates how to use `case` in an `on` clause, similar to a `where` clause. As others have suggested, you don't need it for the logic you provided and it interferes with the query optimizer.

Comment: No, I only want to use the filter " AND disableddate > getdate() or disableddate IS NULL" if the @getdisabledoptions = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logic you have described you can simplify your `WHERE` expression to:

```
WHERE AffiliationID = @AffiliationID
AND (@GetDisabledOptions = 1 or DisabledDate > GETDATE() or DisabledDate IS NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry, no, I want to filter by the disabled date only if the @GetDisabledOptions = 1.

Comment: @CodyStorch that's not what you say in your question: "@getdisabledoptions = 1 I want to get all of the options"

Comment: @CodyStorch did you try this? If you **do** want to filter by the date if `@GetDisabledOptions = 1` then just change `@GetDisabledOptions = 1` in the query to `@GetDisabledOptions = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boolean expression instead of `case` :

```
where (@GetDisabledOptions = 0 and DisabledDate > GETDATE()) or
      (@GetDisabledOptions = 1 and AffiliationID = @AffiliationID);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
WHERE AffiliationID = @AffiliationID
AND ( @GetDisabledOptions = 1 OR (DisabledDate > GETDATE() or DisabledDate = IS NULL))
```

Comment: You need to do one condition is true in where clause.