# CASE in WHERE inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, where-clause

I want to set 2 different where conditions depending on the value of a variable, that is:

```
if @var=0 then Where fieldFecha='1900/01/01' and if @var=1 then where fieldfecha<>'1900/01/01'
    DECLARE @var int
    SET @var=0
    SELECT * FROM Table
    WHERE fieldFecha=CASE ?????
```

I don't know what to put in the `CASE` because I need to use `fieldFecha= and fielFecha<>`

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: Don't use a `CASE` expression in there `WHERE` at all; use proper boolean logic. A `CASE` won't be SARGable.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) answer explains how to use `case` in an `on` clause and is applicable to `where`. It is rarely the best approach as others have noted.

Answer (score 3):

Try to something like

```
 DECLARE @var int = 0;
 SELECT * FROM Table
 WHERE (@var=0 AND fieldFecha='1900/01/01') OR (@var=1 AND fieldfecha<>'1900/01/01')
```

Also, it depends on what you needs, but in this case you can use `UNION`

Comment: When you use AND, OR clauses, please use brackets for those completely like ((@var=0 AND fieldFecha='1900/01/01') OR (@var=1 AND fieldfecha<>'1900/01/01')). or else if the user adds some extra filters, it would work wrong then.

Comment: I think, if the user adds some extra filters, then the user can add more brackets. In this case, it is not necessary, and it doesn't related to the question