# Use CASE or AND/OR in WHERE Clause To Limit Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I know there are lot of similar questions and I went through about 20 of them looking for an answer.  Most set a single variable, or used the AND/OR format that I currently have.

I am trying to create a function where I pass in a combination of City, State, Zip and Country and it locates and returns all information.  If I use the OR method the first option will return results if Zip and Country are NOT NULL, but then the option where only Zip is NOT NULL could also return a result.  These are in the order I want them evaluated (top to bottom).  I'm only retuning one value, but I can't guarantee that the results are in the same order, so I'd like to eliminate redundant results.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT TOP(1) City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        (   -- Zip Code, Country: Will find City and State  /* BEST RESULTS */
            @inZip IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            Zip = @inZip AND 
            Country = @inCountry 
        )
        OR
        (   -- City, State, Country:  Will find first Zip Code in City, State
            @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inState IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            City = @inCity AND 
            (State_abbr = @inState OR State_long = @inState) AND 
            Country = @inCountry 
        )
        OR
        (   -- City, State: Will find first Zip Code in City, State. Will find Country
            @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inState IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            City = @inCity AND 
            (State_abbr = @inState OR State_long = @inState) 
        )
        OR          
        (   -- City, State, Zip: Will find Country
            @inState IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            (State_abbr = @inState AND State_long = @inState) AND 
            Country = @inCountry 
        )
        OR
        (   -- City, Zip:  Will find State and Country
            @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inState IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            City = @inCity AND 
            (State_abbr = @inState AND State_long = @inState) 
        )
        OR
        (   -- State, Zip:  Will find City and Country
            @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            City = @inCity AND 
            Country = @inCountry 
        )
        OR
        (
            -- Zip Code: Will find City, State and Country  ** Possible error if Country is not US or Canada
            @inZip IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            Zip = @inZip 
        )
```

This is what I tried with CASE

```
SELECT TOP(1) City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        CASE
            -- Zip Code, Country: Will find City and State  /* BEST RESULTS */
            WHEN ( @inZip IS NOT NULL AND @inCountry IS NOT NULL )
                THEN Zip = @inZip AND Country = @inCountry 

            -- City, State, Country:  Will find first Zip Code in City, State
            WHEN ( @inCity IS NOT NULL AND @inState IS NOT NULL AND @inCountry IS NOT NULL )
                THEN City = @inCity AND (State_abbr = @inState OR State_long = @inState) AND Country = @inCountry 
        END
```

I received

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

which corresponds to the `= in "THEN Zip = @inZip AND Country = @inCountry`.

If using the CASE isn't possible, is it possible to do something different with my OR statements to achieve what I'm looking for?

- MS SQL Server v15.0.2070
- SSMS v18.5

Comment: Alternative approach is to build query based in the values in the application(.net or else) and send prepared query with straightforward conditions to the sql server. Notice that `OR` queries have terrible performance.

Comment: Or even use dynamic SQL if performance is bad.

Comment: @DaleK  I like the idea of the Dynamic SQL.  I tried it and I'm running into an odd error declaring my variables.

Comment: I really like the idea of the Dynamic Query, but I can't execute it in a function

Comment: You can use a `case` in a `where` clause, much like an `on` clause as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297) answer. Performance is likely to suffer, though using `recompile` hint may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the row is only returned once add additional logic to ensure its ignored if already found e.g. replace

```
(
    -- Zip Code: Will find City, State and Country  ** Possible error if Country is not US or Canada
    @inZip IS NOT NULL 
    AND Zip = @inZip 
)
```

with

```
(
    -- Zip Code: Will find City, State and Country  ** Possible error if Country is not US or Canada
    @inZip IS NOT NULL 
    -- Only go through this branch if country is null because otherwise we have handled it elsewhere
    AND @inCountry IS NULL 
    AND Zip = @inZip 
)
```

And use similar logic to handle other similar conditions.

Comment: This will work, but I will need to add more options since I am now being very specific around the variables.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a `UNION ALL` of each set of conditions, add an ordering column and take the first one.

**This should be very performant**, because it uses `MERGE CONCATENATION`, as [Paul White describes](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/t-sql-queries/avoiding-sorts-merge-join-concatenation):

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
    (SELECT TOP(1) 1 AS Ordering, City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        (   -- Zip Code, Country: Will find City and State  /* BEST RESULTS */
            @inZip IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            Zip = @inZip AND 
            Country = @inCountry 
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(1) 2, City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        (   -- City, State, Country:  Will find first Zip Code in City, State
            @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inState IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            City = @inCity AND 
            (State_abbr = @inState OR State_long = @inState) AND 
            Country = @inCountry 
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(1) 3, City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        (   -- City, State: Will find first Zip Code in City, State. Will find Country
            @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inState IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            City = @inCity AND 
            (State_abbr = @inState OR State_long = @inState) 
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(1) 4, City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        (   -- City, State, Zip: Will find Country
            @inState IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            (State_abbr = @inState AND State_long = @inState) AND 
            Country = @inCountry 
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(1) 5, City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        (   -- City, Zip:  Will find State and Country
            @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inState IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            City = @inCity AND 
            (State_abbr = @inState AND State_long = @inState) 
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(1) 6, City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        (   -- State, Zip:  Will find City and Country
            @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
            @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            City = @inCity AND 
            Country = @inCountry 
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(1) 7, City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        (
            -- Zip Code: Will find City, State and Country  ** Possible error if Country is not US or Canada
            @inZip IS NOT NULL 
            AND 
            Zip = @inZip 
        )
) t
ORDER BY ordering;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your CASE example, I'm guessing you are after something like this (?):

```
SELECT TOP(1) City, State_abbr, State_long, Zip, Country, County, Longitude, Latitude
      FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo]
      WHERE
        1 = CASE
                -- Zip Code, Country: Will find City and State  /* BEST RESULTS */
                WHEN ( @inZip IS NOT NULL AND @inCountry IS NOT NULL )
                    THEN 
                        CASE WHEN Zip = @inZip AND Country = @inCountry THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

                -- City, State, Country:  Will find first Zip Code in City, State
                WHEN ( @inCity IS NOT NULL AND @inState IS NOT NULL AND @inCountry IS NOT NULL )
                    THEN 
                        CASE WHEN City = @inCity AND (State_abbr = @inState OR State_long = @inState) AND Country = @inCountry 
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                ELSE 0          
            END
```

Note that the "ELSE 0" parts are optional, and can be removed if you want, since if a CASE doesn't match any condition and falls through to the end, it will return NULL, which will never equal 1.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you almost certainly lose sargability.