# OR condition in Case statements SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.COnfigId = B.COnfigId JOIN Table3 C ON C.TypeId = B.TypeId INNER JOIN Table4 D ON D.ChannelId = B.ChannelId INNER JOIN Table5 E ON E.NoticeId = A.NoticeId WHERE E.NoticeCode = CASE 
    WHEN (
            D.Channel = 'Post'
            OR (
                D.Channel = 'Email'
                AND C.IsValue = 1
                )
            )
        THEN 'P'
    WHEN (
            (
                D.Channel = 'Email'
                AND C.IsValue = 0
                )
            OR D.Channel = 'Msg'
            )
        THEN 'I'
            OR 'E'
            OR 'N'
    END
```

OR condition in THEN 'I' OR 'E' OR 'N' is not working.

Is there any alternative for this? Please suggest.

Comment: Your query makes no sense, and you haven't explained it elsewhere.. Think about if I sent you to the shops, saying "If they have eggs or they have bread and it is freshly baked then potatoes or carrots or cereal" - it makes no sense

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** in T-SQL (like `a+b`) that returns **one, atomic value** - not a block of code, not a "list" of values - just ONE, atomic value$

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: QUestion Edited

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260297/92546) answer may help clear up how to use a `case` _expression_ in an `on` clause. The same is true of a `where` clause. Performance is likely to suffer, though a `recompile` hint might help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `case`.  Something like this:

```
where (a.code = 'A' and b.code = 'P') or
      (a.code = 'B' and a.value = 1 and b.code = 'P') or
      (a.code = 'B' and a.value <> 1 and b.code in ('I', 'N', 'E'))
```

and so on for whatever your full logic is.

Comment: Edited my question.