# Using Case When and Between as condition in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a problem with my T-SQL query. There is one table where I want to count everything but when `canceldate` (it's a column with dates) is null then `@currentdate` (that is a parameter) should be between `startdate` and `enddate`. Else `@currentdate` should be between `startdate` and `canceldate`.

Here is my code but still i don't know how should i build it.

```sql
declare @currentdate as date

select count(*) from Table 
where
  case when Canceldate is null then 
    @currentdate between startdate and enddate
  else 
    @currentdate between startdate and canceldate
group by personalnum
```

Comment: Dr. Linoff has provided the correct answer. It is possible to use a `case` expression in a `where` (or `on`) clause as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260297/92546), but the performance is likely to suffer considerably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `case`; `coalesce()` does exactly what you want:

```
select count(*)
from Table 
where @currentdate between startdate and coalesce(canceldate, enddate)
group by personalnum;
```

The statement of your problem does not mention a need for `group by`, but that is part of your code.

Comment: Syntax error Gordon? I'm betting you started making a `between` answer and then switched to comparison operator logic.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I tried this but I am geting this error:
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis . . . That is *exactly* what happened.