# SQL Case = Multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to create a `CASE` when my `@ReportId = A` then return a list of values. Else `@reportId = @reportId`

I've attempted to wrong around this by possibly listening every condition but this issue is that I would like all of these ids returned when `@ReportId = 'A'`

How can I achieve this in my SQL Case?

```
SELECT RT.ReportTitle, RT.ReportCode, RT.ReportID, 
FROM dbo.reportTitles As RT
WHERE LEFT(RT.ReportCode, 2) = 
    CASE 
    WHEN @ReportID= 'A' THEN (01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09)
    ELSE @ReportID
    END
ORDER BY RT.ReportTitleASC
```

My expected outcome would be to Select from `dbo.reportTitles` Where `@ReportId` are LIKE the list of ids when `@ReportID = 'A'`

If it is not `'A'` I'd like it to be using the original value that `ReportID` is.

Comment: I'm not clear what results you want when `@ReportID <> 'A'`

Comment: If `@ReportID`  does not equal `'A'` i'd like ReportID just to be the value that is passed. In every situation it's currently an integer but one where  the `ReportID` = `'A'` so I'm attempting to create the case to return the list of ids when it is `'A'` and just return its original value when it's not. Hope that clears it up

Comment: You can use a `case` expression in a `where` clause, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260297/92546) answer for an `on` clause. That said, Dale K's answer is easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use regular `AND/OR` logic... no need for a `case`.

```
WHERE (
    @ReportID = 'A'
    AND LEFT(RT.ReportCode, 2) IN (01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09)
) OR (
    @ReportID = CAST(LEFT(RT.ReportCode, 2) AS VARCHAR(2))
)
```

Note: This will only handle ReportCodes up to 99... if you need more you'll need to increase the sizes.