# How to use case in a where clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT col1,col2
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE
(CASE WHEN col1 > 5 THEN col2) > 10
OR
(CASE WHEN col1 <= 5 THEN col2) > 20
```

I am trying to achieve a result set that will give me the following information:
In case that col1>5 then retrieve all the values in col2 that are larger then 10
OR
In case that col1 <= 5 then retrieve all the values in col2 that are larger then 20 ,
my question is: is the method above correct for filtering out that result set?

Comment: Yes, provided you explain what you want What does `then display only col2>10 ` mean? Display rows only if `col2` is greater than 10? You don't need `CASE` for that

Comment: you can simply put your requirement in `where` clause - like `WHERE (col1>5 AND col2>10) OR (col1<=5 AND col2>20`

Comment: Your question needs to be phrased clearer, you don't normally use a *case expression* to filter rows, and what does `then display only col2>10` mean?

Comment: `display only col2 > 10` what does that mean? Display TRUE? Display one or the other column only if COL2 > 10? T-SQL has no boolean type so you can't use a boolean expression as a value. If you want to return something that can be translated to TRUE/FALSE you need to return 1 or 0 explicitly.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260297/92546) answer explains how to use a `case` expression in a `join` condition. It also applies to a `where` clause. Expect performance to range from dreary to abysmal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display only rows where col2 is greater than 10 or 20 you don't need `CASE`. You can use `OR`

```
select col1, col2
from table1
where (col1>5 and col2>10) OR (col1<=5 and col2>20)
```

If on the other hand you want to display whether COL2 is above or below another number, you need a CASE in the SELECT clause, not WHERE.

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
    CASE WHEN COL1 > 5 THEN IIF(COL2>10,1,0)
         WHEN COL1 <=5 THEN IIF(COL2>20,1,0)
    END
FROM table1
```

T-SQL has no boolean type so a boolean expression can't be used as a value. If you want to return something that can be translated to TRUE or FALSE by the client application you need to return it explicitly.

`IIF` is a shortcut for `CASE WHEN condition THEN a ELSE b END`.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question, the meaning is, if col1>5 then display col2>10, the col2>10 is not a condition

Comment: @Aby_g  again, what does this even mean? Do you want to display `TRUE` or `FALSE`? You can't just display `col2>10` in SQL - especially in T-SQL which has no boolean

Comment: @Aby_g I added a different query that may answer your question. You really need to explain what you want though