# Critical scenario in CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This code has a `CASE` statement in the `ON` clause of a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    A.*, b.*
FROM
    tableA AS s 
INNER JOIN
    stage.product AS t ON s.Chain_code = CASE t.chain_id   
                                             WHEN 1 THEN 'EPRC' 
                                             WHEN 3 THEN 'FSC' 
                                             WHEN 3 THEN 'PRC' 
                                             WHEN 7 THEN 'CM' 
                                         END 
                       AND s.item_number = REPLACE(t.item_id, '-', '')
```

Can I map 3 in `CASE` statement for FSC and PRC BOTH ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: That CASE prevents the use of indexes and *doesn't* make writing the query any easier. Replace it with `OR` and `AND` clauses instead eg `(chain_id=1 AND Chain_Code='EPRC') OR (chain_id=3 and chain_code IN (FSC','PRC')`

Comment: No, 3 can't be assigned to two different values.  Once the case statement encounters a matching value it exits.  So all 3's will be assigned FSC in your example.  you could however have additional critieria such as when 3 and when X=something and when that's true assign FSC, when not true assign PRC.  but that assumes you have a way to delienate when you want FSC and when you want PRC

Comment: so how can  all condition get executed with 3 twice, once with FSC and then with prc any way? please help

Comment: Provide sample data from tableA and product showing what you have and your expected results..  Are you wanting to have more rows in the result.  THe final result is unclear to me and sample data with expected results showing this situation would help.

Comment: On the surfice we could select from the table product twice when 3 is in chain_id and union the results; in a subquery but that seem's very odd.  Which is why sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: @xQbert: Actually I am updating the tablea with product table. and FSC and PRC both are mapped with 3 .

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ provies a simple means to create the sample data, copy and paste into and an ascii table will be generated for you which you can then copy and paste ito your question formatting it as code block to get the formatting right.

Comment: @AngelD'souza... Think about that for a second: if 3 is in your tablea how can 1 record have both values?  it doesn't make sense to me.  Would you want the record duplicated in tableA? Would you want it stored as both 'FSC, PRC' ? which violates 3rd normal form... what's the expectation?  Maybe there's a business rule which needs to be added to the case expression beyond "3" to determine which to use making it a compound expression wtih an "AND" in it so both conditions need to be met 3 and 'soemthing else"?

Comment: Thoguh panagiotis Kanvos's response may be what you need to do....

Comment: Conditions like `s.item_number = replace( t.item_id, '-', '')` usually indicate a less well designed database.

Comment: Aside: A [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) _expression_ (not _statement_) returns a single value. There is no equivalent statement for control-of-flow, but [`IF`/`THEN`/`ELSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) statements may be used. It is good practice to include an explicit default (`ELSE`) clause to show that you thought about the possibility and chose an appropriate value.

Comment: <bad idea> You can complicate the `case` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256848/can-i-use-case-statement-in-a-join-condition/10260297#10260297), but it doesn't make it any clearer and performance is likely to suffer. </bad idea> Just go with `and`/`or` logic and use formatting to make the intent clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `=` and `IN ()` in the same `CASE` clause. You'll need to rephrase the join predicate, as in:

```
select s.*, t.*
from tableA as s 
join stage.product as t on (
       t.chain_id = 1 and s.Chain_code = 'EPRC'
    or t.chain_id = 3 and s.Chain_code in ('FSC', 'PRC')
    or t.chain_id = 7 and s.Chain_code = 'CM'
 ) and s.item_number = replace( t.item_id, '-', '')
```