# In SQL Server validate if a string contains only numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string `'1523987654'` and I need to check if only have numbers.

First I had used `ISNUMERIC`, but it dosen't worked with `'.'`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
ISNUMERIC('.') = 1
 THEN 1 ELSE 
0
 END
```

I had try with LIKE, but without sucess

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
'1523987654'  LIKE '[0-9]'
 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: LIKE '%[0-9]%' (don't you need the %'?)

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522056/how-to-determine-the-field-value-which-can-not-convert-to-decimal-float-int-i