# mssql convert varchar to float

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a field value productlength of 0.123. This is from a view and has a data type of varchar.

I need to convert it to a float or numeric value so as o perform math comparisons.

convert(float,productlength)
and 
cast(productlength as float) both do not work.

`error varchar cant be converted to float` or somethiing liek that.

From what I have read varchar can simply not be converted to a numeric string?

Any clever ways around this?

Comment: `select CONVERT(float, '0.123')` works. Are u sure ther're no extra characters in that variable?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can convert varchars to floats, and you can do it in the manner you have expressed.  Your varchar must not be a numeric value.  There must be something else in it.  You can use IsNumeric to test it.  See this:

```
declare @thing varchar(100)

select @thing = '122.332'

--This returns 1 since it is numeric.
select isnumeric(@thing)

--This converts just fine.
select convert(float,@thing)

select @thing = '122.332.'

--This returns 0 since it is not numeric.
select isnumeric(@thing)

--This convert throws.
select convert(float,@thing)
```

Comment: Just be aware that `ISNUMERIC` can have some [funny behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522056/how-to-determine-the-field-value-which-can-not-convert-to-decimal-float-int-i/4522185#4522185).

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
Try_convert(float,[Value])
```

See 
https://raresql.com/2013/04/26/sql-server-how-to-convert-varchar-to-float/

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @INPUT VARCHAR(5) = '0.12',@INPUT_1 VARCHAR(5)='0.12x';
select CONVERT(float, @INPUT) YOUR_QUERY ,
case when isnumeric(@INPUT_1)=1 THEN CONVERT(float, @INPUT_1) ELSE 0 END AS YOUR_QUERY_ANSWERED
```

above will return values

however below query wont work

```
DECLARE @INPUT VARCHAR(5) = '0.12',@INPUT_1 VARCHAR(5)='0.12x';
select CONVERT(float, @INPUT) YOUR_QUERY ,
case when isnumeric(@INPUT_1)=1 THEN CONVERT(float, @INPUT_1) ELSE **@INPUT_1** END AS YOUR_QUERY_ANSWERED
```

as @INPUT_1 actually has varchar in it.

So your output column must have a varchar in it.