# How to i solve "Error converting data type varchar to numeric" in group by?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

How to solve this error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric".I have tried

```
        SET ANSI_WARNINGS off;
```

but only warning message is gone but error is still there.
My code is

```
SELECT tblLogin.FullName,
       SUM(CAST(tblDetails.Productivity_Hours AS decimal(9,2))) AS [hours]
FROM tblTaskDetails
INNER JOIN tbltsheet ON tblTaskSheet.TaskId=tblDetails.TaskId
INNER JOIN tblLogin ON tblLogin.UserId=tblTaskSheet.UserId
INNER JOIN tblTCategory ON tblDetails.CatId=tblTCategory.CatId
WHERE dbo.tbltsheet.TaskDate>= '12/28/2013'
  AND tbltsheet.TaskDate<='12/31/2013'
  AND tblTCategory.CatName LIKE 'abc'
GROUP BY tblLogin.FullName
ORDER BY [hours] DESC
```

Comment: Why not get to the root of the problem and store your numeric data in the correct format rather than having to validate it and cast it every time you use it? Aaron Bertrand has written a good article on [choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IsNumeric` to validate your type.

```
   WHERE dbo.tbltsheet.TaskDate>= '12/28/2013'
      AND tbltsheet.TaskDate<='12/31/2013'
      AND tblTCategory.CatName LIKE 'abc'
      AND ISNUMERIC(tblDetails.Productivity_Hours) =1
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dcef0/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Try to find these values which can't be converted to a numeric:

```
select Productivity_Hours from tblDetails where ISNUMERIC(Productivity_Hours)=0
```

Also you can use CASE statement to avoid these wrong values (accept them as 0 value):

```
SELECT tblLogin.FullName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(tblDetails.Productivity_Hours)=1  
                     THEN CAST(tblDetails.Productivity_Hours AS decimal(9,2))
                     ELSE 0
                END
        ) AS [hours]
FROM ....
```

Comment: It is worth noting that ISNUMERIC() will return 1 for the value "9,999" as comma characters can still be numeric, but these will not convert into DECIMAL. Rather than munging the value, you could try REPLACE() to remove the offending values before converting.

Comment: @user3056839 You're right to check if it is decimal you can use `ISNUMERIC(tblDetails.Productivity_Hours + 'e0')`. [Here is a good explanation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522056/how-to-determine-the-field-value-which-can-not-convert-to-decimal-float-int-i/4522185#4522185)