# SQL Server : SUM () for only numeric values, ignoring Varchar values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need some help as I am learning SQL so I am at a beginner level. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

My question is: I want to (add) sum up a column that have mix values of `varchar` and `decimal`. I want to ignore the `varchar` values and sum only `decimal`. My column is like this:

```
Column1  
-------
0.1  
Z  
0.4  
2.1  
2.1  
Z
```

And I need the sum that is in this case it should be: `4.7`

I tried using `CASE` but I failed to solve it

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN ISNUMERIC(Column1) = 1 
              THEN .(if true how i add them?). 
              ELSE .(and if false how i ignore them?). 
         END) AS Total 
FROM
    TABLE_Name
```

I am not good in explaning things, but I hope you can understand me what I am trying to do.

If this question is already answered please give me directions to that question and my appologise for that.. Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc920/4

Comment: The answer is to store data in the right place, to never have the problem to sum a non-numeric column!

Comment: This is a **clear sign** of a **horribly bad** database design - you should **fix that FIRST!** before wasting more time on trying to sum up such a messy column ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use `WHERE` clause with `CAST`:

```
SELECT SUM(Cast(Column1 as numeric(10,2))) as Total
FROM TABLE_Name
Where IsNumeric(Column1) = 1
```

Result:

```
TOTAL
4.7
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca2eb/2).

**EDIT:**

As @funkwurm pointed out, the column has a chance to have the value '.' (dot):

```
SELECT SUM(Cast(Column1 as numeric(10,2))) as Total
FROM TABLE_Name
Where IsNumeric(Column1 + 'e0') = 1
```

[**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01bad/2).

Comment: Thank you very much. Really Quick answer :)

Comment: As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4522185/2684660) I would recommend doing `IsNumeric(Column1 + 'e0') = 1`. If I change the SqlFiddle to have a row with value `.` for `Column1`, it breaks.

Comment: @funkwurm: Thanks. I respect your opinion. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can "ignore" a row by adding 0.

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(Column1)=1 THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,5), Column1) --add the value to the sum
            ELSE 0 --add 0 (i.e. ignore it)
        END)
    AS Total
FROM
    TABLE_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select sum(case when isnumeric(cast(Column1 as decimal)) 
then cast(column1 as decimal) else 0 end) as total from table
```

assuming your field is varchar type

Answer (score 0):

Why not using TRY_CONVERT:

```
SELECT SUM(TRY_CONVERT(float,Column1) AS Total
FROM TABLE_Name
```

Shortest query and easy to read! TRY_CONVERT returns NULL if conversion fails (e.g. if there are text values in Column1)

This Functions exists since SQL Server 2012 (i think).

**@Jim Chen:**

Isnumeric is a bit tricky a this point! In your solution there would be a problem if the value '-' or '+' is inside a Column:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('+')    --returns TRUE!
SELECT ISNUMERIC('-')    --returns TRUE!
```

**==> SUM will FAIL!**